uniswap v3 close_position error ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}
I try to close my opened uniswap v3 positions with .close_position()  method, but get this error:
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}

So it find my position id 1547621 but crashing on close_position
why this can happen and how to fix?
this is script:
from uniswap import Uniswap
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

provider = "https://polygon-rpc.com"    # can also be set through the environment variable `PROVIDER`

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(provider))
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

address = "0x2017b2ad2e3f25F1F9354981Fd9a06341d178De5"          # or None if you're not going to make transactions
private_key = "xxx"  # or None if you're not going to make transactions
version = 3                      # specify which version of Uniswap to use

uniswap = Uniswap(address=address, private_key=private_key, version=version, provider=provider, web3 = web3)

# Some token addresses we'll be using later in this guide
#eth = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#bat = "0x0D8775F648430679A709E98d2b0Cb6250d2887EF"
#dai = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"
usdce = Web3.to_checksum_address("0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174")
wbtc = Web3.to_checksum_address("0x1bfd67037b42cf73acf2047067bd4f2c47d9bfd6")
nfpm_contract_address = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88"
print(uniswap.get_price_input(wbtc, usdce, 10**8))

print(uniswap.get_liquidity_positions())

for p in uniswap.get_liquidity_positions():
    #uniswap.approve(p)
    print(p)
    print(uniswap.close_position(p))

#uniswap.close_position()

